# Reading forms in ms word document in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi i am using Apache POI XWPF to read the word document but i am not able to read the forms inside the word documents. Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: After a lot of research i came to know that nothing was useful in reading the forms as far as of my knowledge we can achieve it through reading the xml file directly i am trying in that direction will let you guys know when i am done

Comment: I've got a similar problem -- need to update an existing document with a form in it. Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest parsing and changing the xml files directly / or via poi. If you rename the docx file to zip and unpack it, you can perform a full text search in order to find the correct xml and spot r'to change.